How should we think about functional differentiation
I've been introduced to the following notion of functional differentiation:

Let $F: \Phi \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a linear functional on $\Phi$ (understood as a space of sections over a manifold $M$). Then, $F$ is said to be differentiable if $$F[\phi+\delta \phi]-F[\phi]= \int_M\delta \phi^i dF_i [\phi] dx^n  $$ for some functional (or functional "distributions"?) $dF_i[\phi]$. Then $dF_i[\phi]\equiv \frac{\delta F}{\delta \phi^i}$ is said to be its functional derivative.

I apologize for the lack of rigor in the definition of $\Phi$. This is from Bryce deWitt's The Global Approach to Quantum Field Theory, and he intentionally leaves the definition loose, allowing for the flexibility he might need. However, it is understood that the $\delta \phi^i$ are bundle coordinates of the variation $\delta \phi$, and for most purposes the space of variations is taken to be of $C^{\infty}$ and of compact support.
This seems to be a cumbersome definition. One of the most early examples is that $$\frac{\delta \phi^i}{\delta \phi ^j}=\delta^i_j \delta(x-x')$$ where the functional is understood to be the value of $\phi^i$ at $x$. I can somewhat see this by starting out with this definition and rewriting it as integration against a delta function. However, in the following exercise, the author says that the reader should properly be "readily able" to show that $$F[\phi]=\frac{1}{2}\int_M K_{ij}^{\mu} \phi^i \partial_{\mu} \phi^j dx^n$$ has second functional derivative $\frac{\delta ^2 F}{\delta \phi^j \delta \phi^i}=K_{ij}^\mu \partial_\mu \delta(x-x')+\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu K_{ij}^\mu \delta(x-x')$ if the $K$'s are antisymmetric in their lower indices.
I'm not asking help in calculating this specifically, but I'm having extreme difficulty in applying the above definition to expressions as complex as this. What I did was use the compact support of the functions and their differentiability to integrate by parts and all that; but I wonder, is this how you're supposed to think about it? How does someone comfortable with functional differentiation think about it? Can we apply this as an operator on the functional in the same way that we end up thinking about regular functions' differentiation?
Additionally, if you could redirect me to resources that deal with this kind of functional differentiation I would appreaciate it. The kind of functional differentiation I am used to doesn't really (at least, seem to) involve distributions,

To answer your question, we can utilize the concept of Fréchet derivatives, which is the analogue of derivatives in normed spaces. Because I have not learned the calculus on general normed spaces fully in English I cannot provide you useful references, but if you are interested in it, you can look at "Banach-Hilbert Spaces, Vector Measures and Group Representations" by Tsoy-Wo Ma. I think it is hard to read for non-mathematicians (At least it was so for me, who are majoring in economics). It is focusing on the special space called Banach space (and $\Phi$ is not a Banach space generally), but almost all facts on Fréchet derivatives in this book also hold for general normed spaces.

Let $X$, $Y$ be a normed space equipped norms $|| \cdot ||_X$ and $|| \cdot ||_Y$ respectively, $\phi \in X$ be fixed and $U \subseteq X$ be an
open neighborhood of $\phi$. Then a function $F:U \to Y$ is called Fréchet differentiable at $\phi$ iff there exists a bounded linear mapping $dF[\phi](\cdot) : X \to Y$ called Fréchet derivative of $F$ with respect to $\phi$ such that
$$\lim_{||\delta \phi||_X \, \to \, 0} \frac {||F(\phi + \delta \phi) - F(\phi) - dF[\phi](\delta \phi)||_Y} {||\delta \phi||_X} = 0$$
where $\delta \phi \in X \backslash \{0\}$.

You can check the consistency of this definition with the ordinary derivative on $\mathbb R$; When $X, Y=\mathbb R$,
$$dF[\phi](\delta \phi) = \frac {dF(\phi)} {d \phi} \delta \phi$$
where the derivative in the right hand side is understood as the ordinary derivative. On the other hand, when $X=\Phi, Y=\mathbb R$, if you use the conventional notation for $dF[\phi]$ with the integral
$$dF[\phi](\delta \phi) = \int_M \delta \phi \cdot dF[\phi] \, dy^n$$
(It is an abuse of notation for $dF$, sorry)
then we have the definition of Fréchet differentiability like
$$\lim_{||\delta \phi||_\Phi \, \to \, 0} \frac {|F(\phi + \delta \phi) - F(\phi) - \int_M \delta \phi \cdot dF[\phi] \, dy^n|} {||\delta \phi||_\Phi} = 0$$
for some norm $||\cdot||_\Phi$ in $\Phi$. So your definition of the functional derivative is the special case of this where the numerator is identically equal to zero (which is the case $F$ is linear). Therefore, in a sense of Fréchet derivatives, the only difference between the ordinary differentiation and the functional differentiation is the space we consider. The chain rule, the differentiation for linear mappings or more generally for polynominals, hold in terms of Fréchet derivative.

In the below, I show how we can consider functional derivatives as Fréchet derivatives, so if you are not interested in details for them, just ignore it.

As the same for ordinary derivatives, to consider the derivative for the composition of mappings, the chain rule on Fréchet derivatives is useful.

Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be normed spaces, $\phi \in X$ with an open neighborhood $U$ and $F:U \to Y$ be Fréchet differentiable at $\phi$, $V \subseteq Y$ be an neighborhood of $F(\phi)$ and $G:V \to Z$ be Fréchet differentiable at $F(\phi)$. Then the following equality holds:
$$d(G \circ F)[\phi](\cdot) = dG[F(\phi)](\, dF[\phi](\cdot) \,)$$
It is same as the chain rule on $\mathbb R$.

Like your example, when considered functionals are linear with respect to $\phi$, we can use the following powerful statement:

Let $X$, $Y$ be normed spaces, $\phi \in X$ be arbitrary, and $F:X \to Y$ be bounded and linear. Then $F$ is Fréchet differentiable at $\phi$ and we have
$$dF[\phi]=F$$
That is, the Fréchet derivative of the linear mapping is the linear mapping itself. Let us call it "linear-mapping-differentiation". It is also same as in an Euclid space. That is, for a linear map $A: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$,
$$\frac {d(Ax)} {dx} = A$$
where the derivative is understood as Jacobian.


(It is a technical problem, so if you are not interested in what norm we use then you can ignore)
To consider Fréchet derivatives in your problem, we need clearfy what norm we use for the space $\Phi$. Since we need to work on delta functions (considered as the linear form on $\Phi$) and Fréchet derivatives must be bounded as its definition, we use the norm
$$|| \phi || = \sup_{x \in M} | \phi (x)|$$
where $| \cdot |$ is a Euclid norm on $\Phi$ (We indentify $\Phi$ as a vector-valued function on Euclid space). Whether this is a well-defined norm or not depends on the assumption that every element of $\Phi$ is $C_{\infty}$ (Or more precisely, $C_0$, to get boundedness with the later condition) and has a compact support. By this norm the delta function becomes bounded as a linear form on $\Phi$. We use this norm also for the space $\pi_i (\Phi)$ where $\pi_i$ is a projection from $\Phi$ to their $i$th coordinates. In this case, $| \cdot |$ becomes an absolute value.
Also, to consider the partial derivative $\partial_\mu$ as a bounded linear mappings, we consider the norm
$$||| \phi ||| = \sup_{x \in M} \{| \phi (x)| + \sum_\mu | \partial_\mu \phi (x)| \}$$
and consider $\partial_\mu : \Phi ' \to \Phi$ where $\Phi$ is a normed space equipped with $||\cdot||$ and $\Phi '$ is one equipped with $||| \cdot |||$.
Note that, in this case, a bounded linear form on $\Phi$ need NOT to be represented as integrals with some function, e.g. delta functions. It is noticed in your definition of functional derivatives as

(or functional "distributions"?)



Now let us work on your first example to see how this concept is applied. We identify $\Phi$ as a vector-valued function on Euclid space, as $\phi = (\phi_k)_k$. Then for a bounded linear map $A_j (\phi_j) = (\delta_{jk} \phi_j)_k$, we have
$$dA_j[\phi_j] = A_j$$
by linear-mapping-differentiation.

Consider the function $B_i(\phi) = \phi_i$. Then we have,
$$dB_i[\phi] = B_i$$

Together these results with the chain rule where the case $F=A_j$, $G=B_i$, we have, for $\forall \, \delta \phi_j \in \pi_j(\Phi)$,
$$d(B_i \circ A_j)[\phi_j](\delta \phi_j) = dB_i [A_j(\phi_j)] \,(dA_j [\phi_j] \,(\delta \phi_j)) = B_i(A_j(\delta \phi_j)) = B_i((\delta_{jk} \delta \phi_j)_k) = \delta_{ji} \delta \phi_j$$
Note that $B_i \circ A_j (\phi_j) = \phi_i(\phi_j)$. Therefore, we conclude $d \phi_i(\phi_j)[\delta \phi_j] = \delta_{ij} \, \delta \phi_j$. Let us see this result is consistent with your example. Consider the following conventional notation:
$$d \phi_i(\phi_j)[\delta \phi_j (x)] = \int_M \delta \phi_j (y) \frac {\delta \phi_i} {\delta \phi_j} (y) dy^n$$
In the above equality, I put $\delta \phi_j(x)$ to emphasize $\delta \phi_j$ is a function on M. We have the following when we consider the integral of a delta function:
$$\delta_{ij} \, \delta \phi_j(x) = \int_M \delta \phi_j(y) \delta_{ij} \delta(y-x) dy^n$$
Since we can take $\delta \phi_j$ arbitrarily and $d \phi_i(\phi_j)[\delta \phi_j] = \delta_{ij} \, \delta \phi_j$, we have
$$\frac {\delta \phi_i} {\delta \phi_j} (y) = \delta_{ij} \delta(y-x)$$

To treat your exercise exceeds my ability because we need the notation of second derivatives and the general chain rule with partial derivatives to calculate as we did above, so if you are interested in that, you must learn calculus on general normed spaces. Loosely speaking, consider $F$ as $F(\alpha, \beta) = \frac{1}{2}\int_M \sum_{i, j, \mu} K_{ij}^{\mu} \alpha_i \beta_{j, \mu} dx^n$, and put $\alpha = \phi$ and $\beta = (\partial_\mu \phi_j)_{j, \mu}$ and apply the general chain rule to conclude. Since $F$ and $\partial_\mu$ is linear, we can use linear-mapping-differentiation here.
